# How can get text value in ready function Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
  <input class="span5" type="hidden" name="number" id="number" value="">

    $(this).ready
    ( 
     function() 
     {
         $('#number').on('blur', function() {
            term = $(this).val();
            alert(term);
         });
     }
    );
```

How can I get value Number???

Comment: Please read jQuery documentation before ask such question.

Comment: use change event, blur will not work for hidden field..

Comment: i've already used it, but it didn't work....

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$(document).ready()` not `$(this).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#number').on('blur',function() {
    term = $(this).val();
    alert(term);
  });
});
```

Please see jQuery [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for further details.

Comment: @meandme, how is that hidden field `#number` getting a `blur` event?  Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

why do you use `$(document).ready ( function()`  when **you can shorten it to** 
`$(function()` and hence you can get your value like

```
$(function(){
 $('#number').on('blur',function() {
term = $(this).val();
});
});
```

Comment: i used it cause i want get number's value for autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

its wrong. how will you get an 'onblur' event for a hidden field ? Hidden fields are similar to text fields, with one very important difference! The difference is that the hidden field does not show on the page. Therefore the visitor can't type anything into a hidden field, which leads to the purpose of the field: To submit information that is not entered by the visitor.